What would the uncertainty of a dilute solution in a volumetric flask be?
I am writing a lab report as a homework, and I have finished it and handed it to my teacher once. She gave me feedback and asked for two things: first thing that she wanted was for me to re-calculate the data with some minor adjustments; the second thing was for me to better calculate the uncertainty for the solution that is used and this is my problem.
I used sodium thiosulfate and the lab provided a 0.5 mol/dm^3 solution, and I needed 0.2 mol/dm^3 solution. So, I used the M1xV1 = M2xV2 equation to calculate the amount of 0.5 mol/dm^3 solution needed to make 100 ml of 0.2 mol/dm^3 solution, the answer is 40 ml. The uncertainty of the graduated cylinder I used to measure the amount of 0.5 mol/dm^3 solution was 0.5 ml, and the uncertainty of the volumetric flask I used to prepare the 0.2 mol/dm^3 solution was 0.1 ml.
Here is my question: is the uncertainty of the 0.2 mol/dm^3 solution the sum of the uncertainties of the graduated cylinder and the volumetric flask, or is it just the uncertainty of the volumetric flask?

Why did you use a cylinder? It has too low accuracy for dilution of solutions. You should use pipettes instead.

If overall uncertainty had not been influenced by the uncertainty of the cylinder, then it would not have mattered what volume you had poured in the cylinder.

As you can guess from Poutnik's question, the major source of error is in the 40 mL. Its relative error is so large (1.25 %) that you could neglect the error in measuring the final volume (0.1 %). Unless the sodium thiosulfate solution was titrated again a standard, its concentration will also have a larger relative error, but you don't know it (if the substance is 99% pure, for example).

The lab didn't have any proper pipettes (any pipettes with any sort of measurement method on them) that I could use at that time. I ended up calculating the overall error of the concentration 1.26% by also adding the 0.1% from the volumetric flask to the 1.25% from the graduated cylinder. Thanks a lot for the help.


Here is my question: is the uncertainty of the 0.2 mol/dm^3 solution the sum of the uncertainties of the graduated cylinder and the volumetric flask, or is it just the uncertainty of the volumetric flask?

The final concentration depends on the initial concentration, the initial volume and the final volume. Thus, the error also depends on the error of these three quantities. How you do the calculation depends on what error-propagation estimate you are using. The simplest one for multiplication and division is to add up the relative errors of the factors to obtain an estimate of the relative errors of the resulting quantity.
This is a worst-case estimate, assuming there is no cancellation of random errors.
If you just pour out the 40 mL from the graduated cylinder into the volumetric flask, there is also a systematic error (volume remaining in the cylinder). If you rinse the graduated cylinder with water and add the rinse to the volumetric flask, you avoid that systematic error (losing some of the measured volume); the remaining (unavoidable) random error is estimated at +/- 0.5 mL by the manufacturer, probably obtained experimentally.

graduated cylinders are usually TD. In any case they should not be used quantitatively unless the final solution is independently standardized. Random errors do cancel that is why they are random. Systematic are more insidious, then biggest problem here is the 0.5M stock solution. It would be better to omit the dilution and accept the larger buret error with the smaller dispensed volume.
